# Codeigniter uploading an image to a path folder but in the no record in the database

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I need some help, I can upload an image to a folder path but in the database there is no record that i insert an image... 
Here's my code

----Controller Code----

```
    public function insert_product()
{
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('product_name','Productname','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('product_price','Amount','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('product_stock','Stock','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('categorie_id','categorie_id','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('product_description','Description','required');
        $config = array
        (
            'upload_path' => './assets/img',
            'allowed_types' => 'jpg|png|jpeg|bmp',
            'max_size'=> 0,
            'filename' => $_FILES['product_image']['name']
    );
    $this->load->library('upload',$config);
    if($this->upload->do_upload('product_image'))
    {
        $uploaddata  = $this->upload->data();
        $product_image=$uploaddata['file_name'];
        // $this->db->insert('product',array('product_image'=>$this->upload->file_name));
    }
    if ($this->form_validation->run()) 
    {
        $data = $this->input->post();
        unset($data['submit']);
        $this->load->model('queries_product');  
        if($this->queries_product->insert_product($data))
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','Successfully Inserted');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','Failed to Insert');
        }
        return redirect('inventory');
    }
    else
    {
        echo validation_errors ();
    }
```

}

-----Model Code-------

```
    public function insert_product($data)
    {   
        return $this->db->insert('product',$data);

    }
```

}

Comment: you're unsetting it `unset($data['submit']);`

Comment: Just from a structual standpoint I would combine my `if's` `if($this->form_validation->run() && $this->upload->do_upload('product_image'))`  When they are separate they seem Uncorrelated.  For example you could upload the image if the validation fails.  The order is important, so it will validate and if that is true, then it will upload the image.  Then inside there do the record insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First Validate form
2. Then upload

---

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() != FALSE) 
{
    $data  = array(
        'product_name' =>  $this->input->post('product_name'),
        'product_price' =>  $this->input->post('product_price'),
        'product_stock' =>  $this->input->post('product_stock'),
        'categorie_id' =>  $this->input->post('categorie_id')
    );

    $this->load->model('queries_product'); 

    $this->load->library('upload',$config);
    if(!$this->upload->do_upload('product_image'))
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','Failed to Upload');
    }
    else
    {
        $uploaddata  = $this->upload->data();
        $product_image=$uploaddata['file_name'];

        if($this->queries_product->insert_product($data))
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','Successfully Inserted');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','Failed to Insert');
        }
        return redirect('inventory');
    }  
}
else
{
    echo validation_errors ();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sir, I use your code given there is no error but when i submit the values and check the database there is no values inserted and no image in the folder path..

Comment: after this `$uploaddata  = $this->upload->data();` add `print_r($uploaddata);die;` amd post data

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (as I mentioned in the comments)

```
if( false != ($valid = $this->form_validation->run()) && $this->upload->do_upload('product_image')){
    $uploaddata  = $this->upload->data();
    $product_image=$uploaddata['file_name'];
    // $this->db->insert('product',array('product_image'=>$this->upload->file_name));
    $data = $this->input->post();
    unset($data['submit']);
    $this->load->model('queries_product');  
    if($this->queries_product->insert_product($data)){
        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','Successfully Inserted');
    }else{
        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','Failed to Insert');
    }
    return redirect('inventory');
}else{
    if(!$valid)
       echo validation_errors();
    else
       $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','Failed to Upload');
}
```

By assigning `false != ( $valid = ...)` in the if condition, we can check on a failure which one actually failed, without doing any other real work.

Also as I mentioned in the comments the order of the arguments in the `if` are important.  If `validation` is done first and returns `false`, PHP already knows the condition will not succeed. That's because the `&&` requires that both sides be `true` and if one side is `false` there is no need to check the other side, so PHP immediately goes to the next condition in the block (the `else` in this case) without doing the upload.